# JSON file is fetched correctly but fetched data are not displayed in console log

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to do a simple ajax request to retrieve a **json** file from the server and store it in a javascript object.

I have tried 2 different methods **.ajax()** method and **.getJSON()**.
Both methods in the Network console seem to fetch the file with result **HTTP/1.1 200 OK**.

But when I tried to output the received data in the console with **console.log(data)** nothing shows up.

I have enabled the cross-origin requests in Firefox as I run my code locally and the web server is on a Rpi(Wordpress).

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://192.168.0.227/json/sysC01.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },

        });


$.getJSON("http://192.168.0.227/json/sysC01.json", function(result){
                console.log(result);
            });
```

As a first step I want to see that the data are received, which I can't at the moment, and afterwards I would like to store the data in a Javascript object and output them inside a div element with a certain format.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: what is the http response in the network tab of your developer console (browser) Is there actually data ?

Comment: check your network tab in google-chrome developer to see the result of your request,maybe your request won't send or don't return successfully and got error

Comment: Write an error function and check whther its throwing error.

Comment: @lonut he told us he receive HTTP/1.1 200 Ok but it can also return an empty value and would say its Ok.

Comment: In  Network console click on the respond and check ` respond` tab in the right hand side window to check whether data is coming or not. `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` does not mean you have the data. it means the request is responded without any errors.

Comment: for both methods I get HTTP/1.1 200 OK, Is there a way to check if I get an empty value? I use Firefox since I enabled Cross-origin requests and because it is not secure for browsing I use Chrome for browsing.

Comment: @ShanilFernando You are right data were not transferred also at the domain field I see "The connection used to fetch this resource was not secure". maybe the browser cuts it off?

Comment: did you try with https ?

Comment: With https I get no response(also no error) and the type field in the network changed from json to plain. I am logged in in the site of course. Maybe there is something in the server-side? I just stored the json files in a folder in the /var/www/html directory. If i request the json file from the url it shows as expected in the browser. I also temporarily disabled the antivirus in case it blocked the insecure communication.

Comment: @ShanilFernando The error showing is "json.parse unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the json data", sorry for the late update I thought I had updated the last comment. After searching the error I could not find anything helpful. Json file syntax has been checked and is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot of different things what fixed the issue was running Chrome from the command line with web security disabled.
The relative command:

> chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security